# Issues with Criteria in SQL

Tags: sql

I am really hoping someone can help me, i have a table as such:

```
Period Client Active
jan-20 x      1
feb-20 y      0
mar-21 z      1 
jan-21 t      0
mar-21 f      1
jan-21 f      0 
dec-20 f      0
```

The period is as format 'YYY-MM-DD'.

I have a table (x) that has multiple periods, clients and an active status of 1 or 0.

I want to pull in only clients where the current month active status is '1' but the active status for all previous months of the current month are '0'.

what i am getting at the moment, is results that show the client, but where i dive deeper into that client, it has months where active status = '1' in previous months, but them periods are excluded from my results, when in actual fact that specific client shouldn't be in my results at all.

FYI - my current period will always be the MAX period within my table (x).

This is the code i am currently using - but is not working as pulling in clients that shouldnt be in there.

```
*SELECT 
e.EmeaChannel,
fc.PeriodKey,
fc2.PeriodKey,
fc.Merchantkey AS Clients,
fc.RevenueActive,
fc2.RevenueActive
 
FROM [Fact].[ClientCountFull] fc

inner join [Fact].[ClientCountFull] FC2 on 
FC2.PeriodKey   >=  DATEADD(MONTH, -16, FC.PeriodKey) 
AND FC2.PeriodKey < FC.PeriodKey

AND FC.MerchantKey = FC2.MerchantKey
AND fc.EmeaChannelKey = fc2.EmeaChannelKey
  
inner join Dimension.EmeaChannel e on e.emeachannelkey = fc.emeachannelkey
inner join dimension.account a on a.MerchantKey = fc.MerchantKey

where  
    AccountStatus = 'Open' 
   and e.EmeaChannel = 'CMS'
  
 and fc.RevenueNew = 1
  and fc.RevenueActive = 1
  and fc2.RevenueActive = 0
 
order by fc.PeriodKey desc*
```

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) Please explain how you know what the current period is?  Is it passed in explicitly?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Hey I have updated my question now.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use aggregation.  Let me start by assuming that `period` has a reasonable format of YYYY-MM rather than using the (rather useless) month name.  Then you can use:

```
select client
from t
where active = 1
group by client
having min(period) = '2021-03';
```

In your case, you will need to convert the `period` to a date -- or at least to YYYY-MM format.  That depends on the database you are using, and date/time functions are notoriously database-dependent.